# Excel: formula to fill text data from sheet based on condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-statements

So, here's the situation. I have a workbook with several sheets. I've got one with a list of companies and their data (Tax ID, address, city, etc.) and another - working one. I have a cell with a drop-down list containing the names of the companies. I'd like Excel to fill in automatically the rest of the data in the cells bellows the one with the name (i.e. Tax ID, city, address, etc.).

For the numerical data I'm using SUMIFS and that's working fine. However, I can't figure out what to use so that Excel could pull the textual information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlookup will help you doing this :

[Vlookup step by step](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php)

Comment: I saw this function, but it's rather limited: for one, the table needs to be sorted and I can't always ensure that. Also, it only looks in the left-most column, whereas my arrangement is different.
Is there no other option? :(

Comment: @zkvvoob: Yes, there is always the option not to abuse Excel for your problem and instead use a tool appropriate to the task. :-) You could create a database and code a frontend to select and retrieve the data through for example. Then you most likely can fit it to your needs as you please.

Comment: OK, thank you both. I'll stick to the Vlookup function. :)